# Comportamiento indefinido en procedencia de operadores

Tags: c, array, optimización

Buenas,

Estoy realizando un programa en C donde necesito ejecutar el siguiente bloque de codigo:

```
uint8_t local_index=0;
uint8_t buffer_start[100];
uint16_t temporal_uint16;

temporal_uint16 = (uint16_t) (buffer_start[local_index++] << 8) | buffer_start[local_index++];
```

La idea es tomar dos bytes consecutivos de un array (dependiendo del valor de local_index en ese momento) y meterlos dentro de una variable del tipo uint16_t realizando operaciones lógicas.

El programa está funcionando correctamente, sin embargo al compilarlo produce el siguiente warning y me gustaría entender por que:

"operation on 'local_index' may be undefined"

Tengo otras alternativas para resolver el problema, lo que quiero es simplemente entender el por que de ese warning, ya que a mi parecer la sintaxis de la linea de codigo es correcta.

Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Los operadores pre-incremento y post-incremento hay que usarlos con cuidado. Tu estás asumiendo que el código a ejecutar es equivalente a este:

```
temporal_uint16  = (uint16_t) (buffer_start[local_index] << 8);
local_index++;
temporal_uint16 += (uint16_t) (buffer_start[local_index]);
local_index++;
```

Pero no tiene por qué ser así. El estándar no especifica en qué momento se ha de producir el incremento. Deja cierto grado de libertad al compilador para elegir la mejor forma de hacerlo. Así, el post-incremento se podría producir al finalizar la ejecución de la línea, luego tu código sería equivalente a este:

```
temporal_uint16  = (uint16_t) (buffer_start[local_index] << 8);
temporal_uint16 |= (uint16_t) (buffer_start[local_index]);
local_index++;
local_index++;
```

Y lo mismo sucede con los pre-incrementos. Podría suceder que se ejecutasen todos en cascada antes de ejecutar ninguna otra operación de la línea actual.

Como norma general, no incluyas varias operaciones de pre-incremento o post-incremento en la misma instrucción si estas operaciones afectan a la misma variable ya que el resultado final dependerá del compilador y no creo que te gusten los resultados.

Puedes optar por trocear la línea:

```
temporal_uint16  = (uint16_t) (buffer_start[local_index++] << 8);
temporal_uint16 |= (uint16_t) (buffer_start[local_index++]);
```

o puedes sustituir los incrementos por sumas:

```
temporal_uint16 = (uint16_t) (buffer_start[local_index] << 8)
                | buffer_start[local_index+1];
local_index+=2;
```

Un saludo.

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que en la misma instrucción accedes a una posición del arreglo a la vez que la modificas e incrementas el índice:

```
(buffer_start[local_index++] << 8) | buffer_start[local_index++]
 \------modificar elemento------/
              \---índice--/                       \---índice--/
```

No está especificado que operación se hará antes:

- `(buffer_start[local_index++] << 8)` antes que `buffer_start[local_index++]`.
- `buffer_start[local_index++]` antes que `(buffer_start[local_index++] << 8)`.

El compilador tiene la libertad de reordenar las operaciones para aplicar optimizaciones, ya sea el desplazamiento de bits a la derecha, el aumento de los índices o la lectura del elemento del array, así que según qué operación se haga antes el resultado será diferente, ergo: la operación puede ser indefinida ya que puede dar resultados diferentes en diferentes compiladores o diferentes configuraciones en el mismo compilador.

Para solucionarlo, deberías separar la operación y aplicarla en el orden que necesites:

```
uint16_t l = (buffer_start[local_index++] << 8);
uint16_t r = buffer_start[local_index++];
temporal_uint16 = (uint16_t) l | r;
```

```
uint16_t r = buffer_start[local_index++];
uint16_t l = (buffer_start[local_index++] << 8);
temporal_uint16 = (uint16_t) l | r;
```